# firebase phone auth not supporting before Lollipop

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am trying to test firebase phone auth for multiple devices, when I try with phones with android 5.0 or later, it works fine. For lower android api's I receive this message:

> This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verifythat the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed. Is app running on a physical device? ]

This is my phone verification block

```
mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
            // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
            //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
            // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
            //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verificaiton without
            //     user action.
            Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);

            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Verification completed.",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // [START_EXCLUDE silenst]
            mVerificationInProgress = false;
            // [END_EXCLUDE]

            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            // Update the UI and attempt sign in with the phone credential
            //updateUI(STATE_VERIFY_SUCCESS, credential);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]

            //signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
            deviceTokenCheck(phoneNumber);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
            // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
            Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);
            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            mVerificationInProgress = false;
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                // Invalid request
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                mPhoneNumberField.setError("Invalid phone number.");
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Quota exceeded.",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }

            // Show a message and update the UI
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            updateUI(STATE_VERIFY_FAILED);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                               PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
            // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
            // by combining the code with a verification ID.
            Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Code Sent.",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            mResendToken = token;

            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            // Update UI
            updateUI(STATE_CODE_SENT);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    };
    // [END phone_auth_callbacks]
}
```

Comment: is it running on physical device or emulator in lower versions

Comment: There is also a problem if you need to send otp in lower devices than 5.0 you have to put country code with mobile number like (+91 987643210).

Comment: And the error message you provide in the question it occur when app running on emulator

Comment: I am adding country code and using real phone.